# How to Create an Discord Server Invite for another server the bot is in (Discord.JS)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How do I create an invite for another server the bot is in?
I have a bot that verifies users with a captcha. It's in a gateway server. I want it to create a invite for the main server that expires in 30 seconds and only 1 person can use it. How would I do that?

Comment: So is the main server the captcha server, or the server the user is being verified in?

Comment: The main server isn't the captcha server, I want it to create a 30second invite with 1 use to the other main server.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution at Grepper and just added it so it matches your script [Grepper](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/discord.js+v12+create+invite)

```
const channel = 'The gateway server id';
channel.createInvite({ maxAge: 0, maxUses: 0 });
```

in the `maxAge` add the time you want it be living...(I'm pretty sure its in seconds) in your case 30 (if the 30 is too fast that means its in miliseconds and you have to use 3000)

and in the `MaxUses` add how many users can use it in your case 1

Comment: @Eternadox to get the invite you would just do this `const invite = channel.createInvite({ maxAge: 0, maxUses: 0 });` and then just `message.channel.send(invite);`